# How to buffer and drop a chunked bytestring with a delimiter?

Tags: akka-stream

Lets say you have a publisher using broadcast with some fast and some slow subscribers and would like to be able to drop sets of messages for the slow subscriber without having to keep them in memory. The data consists of chunked ByteStrings, so dropping a single ByteString is not an option.

Each set of ByteStrings is followed by a terminator ByteString("\n"), so I would need to drop a set of ByteStrings ending with that.

Is that something you can do with a custom graph stage? Can it be done without aggregating and keeping the whole set in memory?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking.  It's also unclear why you are suggesting a custom graph stage as opposed to something like `Flow.filter` or `Flow.map`...

Comment: I'll try to make it clearer. This is a stream of ByteStrings, where multiple ByteStrings make up a file. A single ByteString("\n") marks the end of a file. So normal filters work on individual ByteStrings, but in this case, dropping a single ByteString would result in a corrupt file. The code would need to drop a set up ByteStrings ending with the terminator ByteString("\n").  I know you can use standard operators to combine the ByteStrings in memory so that you only have one per file, but assume that the files a gigabytes in size, so the aim was to not load them into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Avoid Custom Stages**

Whenever possible try to avoid custom stages, they are very tricky to get correct as well as being pretty verbose.  Usually some combination of the standard akka-stream stages and plain-old-functions will do the trick.

**Group Dropping**

Presumably you have some criteria that you will use to decide which group of messages will be dropped:

```
type ShouldDropTester : () => Boolean
```

For demonstration purposes I will use a simple switch that drops every other group:

```
val dropEveryOther : ShouldDropTester = 
  Iterator.from(1)
          .map(_ % 2 == 0)
          .next
```

We will also need a function that will take in a `ShouldDropTester` and use it to determine whether an individual `ByteString` should be dropped:

```
val endOfFile = ByteString("\n")

val dropGroupPredicate : ShouldDropTester => ByteString => Boolean = 
  (shouldDropTester) => {
    var dropGroup = shouldDropTester()

    (byteString) => 
      if(byteString equals endOfFile) {
        val returnValue = dropGroup
        dropGroup = shouldDropTester()
        returnValue
      }
      else {
        dropGroup
      }      
  }
```

Combining the above two functions will drop every other group of ByteStrings.  This functionality can then be converted into a `Flow`:

```
val filterPredicateFunction : ByteString => Boolean =
  dropGroupPredicate(dropEveryOther)

val dropGroups : Flow[ByteString, ByteString, _] =
  Flow[ByteString] filter filterPredicateFunction
```

As required: the group of messages do not need to be buffered, the predicate will work on individual ByteStrings and therefore consumes a constant amount of memory regardless of file size.